# Interpreting Skewness

Tags: self-study, skewness

I'm reading Dr. Shewhart and Wheeler's books, and neither think skewness has value in statistics.

When discussing the central tendency of two independent data sets that share a commonality, like same factory but different assembly line, then how should skewness be presented? Just as a value? Or, can inferences be made about the two independent groups by examining skewness?

Comment: Very little that would be of interest can actually be said on the available information (some things can be said but they're unlikely to be especially revealing in terms of saying anything worth knowing about the workers).  I'd love to see what said author thinks a good answer consists of.

Comment: This qualifies as a self-study question for our site, regardless of whether you are actually getting this from homework. Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Textbook-style exercises also fall under self study. Note that questions that "just ask for opinions" must also be closed (that's a network-wide policy), so that change doesn't help you, it actually makes it harder to reopen your question. If you want to get answers to a textbook style question, you should follow the guidelines for such questions. If you want to rephrase to ask something more directly about skewness, please do so. In either case, please edit your question. I think there's a potentially good question under the surface here.

Comment: Unfortunately, your change invalidates an answer you already have which is a little unfair on the person who responded to that. I'll reopen, but please consider pasting the original back in, at least at the bottom of your present question (with some explanation of how the question comes to be changed)

Answer (score 1):

Since both lines have positive skewness, I can infer that on average the amount of socks produced for both lines is less than the average. There is at least an outliner (e.g.: a day or days) that the workers generate more socks than expected. The first line is more positively skewed than the second line.

A possible explanation is that workers work extremely hard on the days they know their boss come to visit them. The boss visits the first assembly line more often than the second line.